# Total value of foreach

Tags: php, loops, foreach, count

Please Help complete this function I want to count the total value of $answer here.

```
<?php 
  foreach($_POST as $fieldName=> $answer){
   if($answer=="1"){settype($answer, "integer");
   if(is_int($answer)){  
     //I want to echo the total value of $answer. Right now it gives me "1111" instead of "4"       and I want 4.
   }
?>
```

Comment: Can you at least post the initial array value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP language is multitype so you can ease your code just to check the value:

```
$total = 0;
foreach($_POST as $fieldName => $answer)
{
    ( $answer == (int) $answer ) && $total+= $answer;
}
```

Did I get your problem right?

Comment: Thank you all so much for your quick responses!!! All answers worked!!! Thank you much appreciated!

Comment: No problem. If your problem is solved, please accept best answer in your opinion, so the question will no longer be in "open" ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_answer = 0;

foreach($_POST as $fieldName=> $answer)
{

    if($answer=="1"){settype($answer, "integer");
    if(is_int($answer)){  
        $new_answer = $new_answer + $answer 
}

echo $new_answer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can  try this,

```
<?php $myTotal = 0;
  foreach($_POST as $fieldName=> $answer){
   if($answer=="1"){settype($answer, "integer"); }
       if(is_int($answer)){  
          $myTotal +=$answer;
       }
   }
?>
```